# html error arise for this program containig table and colspan

Tags: html, html-table

Why is the following html code not working for usig colspan in the table?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>table</title>
    </head>

    <body>      
        <table height="200" width="200" border="1">    
            <tr>
                <td colspan="9">EXAM SCHEDULE</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">D</td>
                <td colspan="4">T</td>
                <td colspan="2">V</td>
            </tr>    
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is what i get from the code :

[image]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: colspan have different values but in output colspan is same for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no major error in your html except some unwanted html, body tags are there which I have removed, but you could be able to see the difference only after adding more columns into it like the below html code:

```
<html>
 <head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<title>table</title>
</head>

<body>      
<table height="200" width="200" border="1">

<tr>
<td colspan="9">EXAM SCHEDULE</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3">D</td>
<td colspan="4">T</td>
<td colspan="2">V</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>t1</td>
<td>u1</td>
<td>g1</td>
<td>t2</td>
<td>u2</td>
<td>g2</td>
<td>u2</td>
<td>t4</td>
<td>u4</td>
</tr>
</table>
    <script>
    $(function(){ 
  $(document).on("click",".seat",function(){
        alert($(this).parent().find('.green').length);
    });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the expected output? The code has no syntax errors.

Table cells can span across more than one column or row. The attributes COLSPAN ("how many across") and ROWSPAN ("how many down") indicate how many columns or rows a cell should take up.

So, EXAM SCHEDULE as specified with colspan=9 will use 9 columns. There will be total 9 columns as per the code.